# JSONPATH FOR saopui

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

Can you please let me know what will the jsonpath for below json:

```
[{
   "cpnSeqNbr": 0,
   "cpnStatusCd": 10,
   "cmpgnId": 37524,
   "cpnSkuNbr": 49579,
   "redeemEndDt": "        "
}]
```

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: what data would you like to extract?

Comment: jsonpath for "cpnStatusCd" element.

Comment: It seems that it is an array, do you like all the values?

Comment: Hi Rao, i need jsonpath for "cpnStatusCd", since there is array , i m confused how to write the jsonpath . Please help.

Comment: Is that all that you get in the response? or you get more values of `cpnStatusCd`?

Comment: As of now one value in future we might get multiple.Can you please let me know the jsonpath for one occurence now.

Comment: Use index to get the respective value if you know to get the single value.

Comment: I really dont know the syntyax...  $.[*].cpnStatusCd is this the correct syntax.

Comment: Do you have a fixed value to verify against? What happened with `jsonpath` that you mentioned? Was that not sufficient? what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would Use a REST API to convert the object into the appropriate path, I'm not sure what language you using so it tough to say what to use. If its JavaScript then use

```
JSON.stringify ([{
   "cpnSeqNbr": 0,
   "cpnStatusCd": 10,
   "cmpgnId": 37524,
   "cpnSkuNbr": 49579,
   "redeemEndDt": "    "
}])
```

or any other APIs equivalence if you are not using JavaScript.

Comment: I m extracting the jsonpath to use in SOAPUI assertion to valiate the reposne.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below JsonPath expression in your SoapUI Assertions.

```
$.[*].cpnStatusCd
```

You can extend this to other fields too, for example: `$.[*].cmpgnId`

You can actually validate if your JsonPath expressions are working or not using online tools such as [JsonPath Expression tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/).

Below image should help understand what needs to be put as the input/JSON URL and expected JsonPath Expression:

[image]

Using JsonPath Expression tester tool, I was able to extract the content/value of `cpnStatusCd = 10` or `cmpgnId = 37524` in your exmaple Json.

You can use the above JsonPath Expression as your SoapUI Assertion for writing Test Cases.